# Pulling Text From a Memo Box Line by Line

Tags: database, delphi, paradox

I need to go through a ton of data that is stored in a paradox table within a Memo field. I need to process this data line by line and process each line.

How can I tell Delphi to fetch each line in the memo field one by one?

Could I use #13#10 as a delimiter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that what is in the memo field uses #13#10 as the line separator then I would use a `TStringList`, and the very useful [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text) property to split the memo field text into separate lines:

```
var
  StringList: TStringList;
  Line: string;
.....
StringList.Text := MemoFieldText;
for Line in StringList do
  Process(Line);
```

Even if your memo field uses Unix linefeeds then this code will interpret the memo field correctly.

Comment: `TStringList` supports parsing text that use `#13#10`, `#13`, and `#10` as line breaks.

Comment: @Remy Documentation states "When setting Text, the value will be parsed by separating into substrings whenever a carriage return or linefeed is encountered. (The two do not need to form pairs)." Is that out of date? I checked the documentation for this very point just before my final grace period edit (i.e. the final sentence).

Comment: no, it is still valid.  When the `LineBreak` property is set to `sLineBreak` (the OS native line break), then all three line break types (`CR`, `LF`, `CRLF`) are looked for.  When the `LineBreak` property is set to something else, then only that value is looked for.

Comment: @remy Thanks. It seems that the documentation is a little lacking in these details

Comment: @David, "a little lacking" is too kind wording.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the field is actually declared in Paradox. If it's a TMemoField, it's pretty easy:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  Line: string;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Text := YourMemoField.GetAsString;
    for Line in SL do
     // Process each line of text using `Line`
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If it's a TBlobField, it's a little more complicated. You need to read the memo field using a `TBlobStream`, and  load the content of that stream into a `TStringList`:

```
// For Delphi versions that support it:
procedure LoadBlobToStringList(const DS: TDataSet; const FieldName: string;
  const SL: TStringList);
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(SL), 'Create the stringlist for LoadBlobToStringList!');
  SL.Clear;
  Stream := DS.CreateBlobStream(DS.FieldByName(FieldName), bmRead);
  try
    SL.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

// For older Delphi versions that do not have TDataSet.CreateBlobStream
procedure LoadBlobToStringList(const DS: TDataSet; const TheField: TField; 
  const SL: TStringList);
var
  BlobStr: TBlobStream;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(SL), 'Create the stringlist for LoadBlobToStringList!');
  SL.Clear;
  BlobStr := TBlobStream.Create(DS.FieldByName(TheField), bmRead);
  try
    SL.LoadFromStream(BlobStr);
  finally
    BlobStr.Free;
  end;
end;

// Use it
var
  SL: TStringList;
  Line: string;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  LoadBlobToStringList(YourTable, YourMemoFieldName, SL);
  for Line in SL do
    // Process each Line, which will be the individual line in the blob field

  // Alternatively, for earlier Delphi versions that don't support for..in
  // declare an integer variable `i`
  for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Line := SL[i];
    // process line of text using Line
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should use the `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` method instead of instantiating the `TBlobStream` class directly.  That allows the DB component to decide the best implementation to use for the stream.

Comment: @Remy: I thought about adding the snippet for that; I'll update my code to show that alternative as well. (It didn't exist in early Delphi versions, and there wasn't a version mentioned in the question; I went with least common demoninator and what I had handy at the time.)

Comment: `CreateBlobStream()` has existed since at least D5 for sure, maybe earlier.

Comment: Possibly; I don't have a version that old (or any prior to that) installed to check. Since the OP didn't specify *any* version, and mentioned `BDE` and `Paradox`, this could be as old as Delphi 1. :) Regardless, I took your suggestion and updated my answer to include both.